# mouse movement with glut

Tags: opengl, glut

I am trying to learn the basics of the opengl Glut , and I am following the tutorial of a site .

I can not understand how I can move the camera in space and not just in two ordinates .

Could you help me ?

I'm using a glutPassiveMotionFunc(mouseMove) function.

```
//MOUSE MOVEMENT----------------------------------------------------------

void mouseMove(int x, int y) {

xOrigin = x;

// this will only be true when the left button is down

if (xOrigin >= 0) {
    // update deltaAngle
    deltaAngle = (x - xOrigin) * 0.001f;

    // update camera's direction
    lx = x + sin(angle + deltaAngle);
    lz = y - cos(angle + deltaAngle);

}
else{
    deltaAngle = (x + xOrigin) * 0.001f;

    // update camera's direction
    lx = x + sin(angle + deltaAngle);
    lz = y - cos(angle + deltaAngle);



   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple coordinate systems in openGL, screen coordinate, eye coordinate, world coordinate, ...

The x and y you get from the mouse callback function are referring to the screen coordinates, which starts from (0,0) from the upper-left corner of the window.

The camera, on the other hand, works on a different level. You didn't mention which version of OpenGL you are using ... but anyways you can read the manual pages for gluLookAt() to learn more about the eye coordinate system.